# How to keep updating and displaying excel information?

Tags: python, excel

I need to have a copy of a worksheet updated every time the original is modified.  The copy ws needs to be opened at all times so everyone can see when it is updated.  So far without working on the code to detect file modification yet, I am just working on being able to update the worksheet.  I have found two ways of doing it, they are below:

1) The first way is using openpyxl.  Doing it this way I think I will have to write data to Todolist2 first then open the file in the excel application.  Then when the original is modified, it will have to close excel before writing updated data back in. Then reopen it.  Below is what I have so far.  Using sleep(10) allows me the chance to update example.xlsx so as to simulate writing new data to Todolist2.  As long as i close Todolist2 after it writes update data to it, it's good, it will not throw permission denied.  (A) However it won't update new data after the first pass.  (B) Is there anyway to have the file open in excel so I can just keep writing updated data to it, instead of closing it out first (file does not need to be saved) ? (second way below allows me to do that).

```
import openpyxl as xl
from copy import copy
import time, os

path1 = 'C:\\example.xlsx'
path2 = 'C:\\Todolist2.xlsx'

wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path1)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path2)
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0]

while True:
    for row in ws1:
        for cell in row:
            ws2[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value
            if cell.has_style:
                ws2[cell.coordinate].font = copy(cell.font)
                ws2[cell.coordinate].border = copy(cell.border)
                ws2[cell.coordinate].fill = copy(cell.fill)
                ws2[cell.coordinate].number_format = 
                copy(cell.number_format)
                ws2[cell.coordinate].protection = copy(cell.protection)
                ws2[cell.coordinate].alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
    wb2.save(path2)
    os.startfile('C:\\Todolist2.xlsx')
    #I will need something here to close out excel to allow python to 
    #write to it again, otherwise it will throw permission denied.
    time.sleep(10)     #during this time I will modify example.xlsx and 
                       #save, so on the next go around it rewrites the 
                       #new data to Todolist1.xlsx.  However, it does not 
                       #update to Todolist2.
```

(2) The second way I'm trying to solve this is with win32com.  This allows me to keep Todolist2 open in excel in windows while it writes to it from example, example1, then example2.  But the problem is, it does not write on the activesheet, it keeps adding additional sheets.  So on this one, If I can find a way to keep rewriting over the active sheet in Todolist2 or after it adds the additional sheet, and I can delete an older sheet that would work too.  (A) whats the function to keep deleting an older sheet?

```
import time, os.path, os
from win32com.client import Dispatch

path1 = 'C:\\example.xlsx'
path2 = 'C:\\Todolist2.xlsx'
path3 = 'C:\\example2.xlsx'
path4 = 'C:\\example3.xlsx'


xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

wb1= xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path1)
wb2= xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path2)

ws1 = wb1.Worksheets(1)
ws1.Copy(Before=wb2.Worksheets(1))

time.sleep(5)

wb3= xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path3)
ws3 = wb3.Worksheets(1)

ws2 = wb2.Worksheets(3)      #it seems by using (3) is the only way it 
                             #allows me to delete one sheet before it 
                             #adds another.
ws2.Delete()
ws3.Copy(Before=wb2.Worksheets(1))

time.sleep(5)

wb4= xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path4)
ws4 = wb4.Worksheets(1)

ws2.Delete()            #I got into trouble here, and throws error even 
                        #though it does the delete and copy
ws4.Copy(Before=wb2.Worksheets(1))
```

Comment: No, excel doesn't allow updating data of open files. You have to close the file first, or use a excel macro that runs inside excel itself.

Comment: @nosklo That's what I thought, but why I am able to do it on the second example with dispatch in win32com?